# Making a back up of A SQL Server Compact Edition Corrupts the database

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-ce

On close of an application written in VB, I need to copy the `.sdf` file, this is the local SQL Server CE database that syncs with the server. Each time we close the app we require a backup to be made.

I am using the `file.copy` method. First I close the connection to the database then copy the file to a specific location.

```
Dim conn As SqlCeConnection = New SqlCeConnection(My.Settings.MyClientConnectionString)
conn.Open()
conn.Close()

Dim tpath As String = My.Settings.CertPath 
Dim path As String = tpath.Replace("db\", "MyDatabase.sdf")
Dim fs As FileStream = File.Create(path)
fs.Close()
File.Delete("C:\db\backup\MyDatabase.sdf")
File.Copy(path, "C:\db\backup\MyDatabase.sdf")
```

The problem arises on the line of code:

```
Dim fs As FileStream = File.Create(path)
```

The database becomes corrupted and has a size of 0 kb.

Has anyone seen this before? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you calling Create on an *existing* database file?  According to the docs, Create *creates or overwrites* a file in the specified path.  In the code you show, calling Create isn't necessary anyway.  Just call File.Copy.

Comment: Yes I am just trying to copy an existing database file. I thought I required the create first. Thank you!!